# Dividindo de um dataframe pelo outro com uma condição

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho dois dataframes, um com marca_x outro com marca_y.

```
df_marca_x = pd.DataFrame([['MARCA_X', 'SALVADOR', 3.5, 'PIZZA'], 
                     ['MARCA_X', 'BELO HORIZONTE', 2.1, 'PIZZA'], 
                     ['MARCA_X', 'BELO HORIZONTE', 2.1, 'PIZZA'], 
                     ['MARCA_X', 'BELO HORIZONTE', 2.0, 'PIZZA'],
                     ['MARCA_X', 'SÃO PAULO', 2.3, 'PIZZA'],
                     ['MARCA_X', 'SÃO PAULO', 2.5, 'PIZZA'],
                     ['MARCA_X', 'SÃO PAULO', 2.4, 'PIZZA'],
                     ['MARCA_X', 'SÃO PAULO', 1.8, 'PIZZA'],], columns=['MARCA', 'CIDADE', 'PRECO', 'PRODUTO'])

df_marca_y = pd.DataFrame([['MARCA_Y', 'SALVADOR', 5.5, 'PIZZA'], 
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'BELO HORIZONTE', 3.1, 'PIZZA'], 
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'BELO HORIZONTE', 1.1, 'PIZZA'], 
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'BELO HORIZONTE', 1.0, 'PIZZA'],
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'SÃO PAULO', 6.3, 'PIZZA'],
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'SÃO PAULO', 7.5, 'PIZZA'],
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'SÃO PAULO', 8.4, 'PIZZA'],
                         ['MARCA_Y', 'SÃO PAULO', 4.8, 'PIZZA'],], columns=['MARCA', 'CIDADE', 'PRECO', 'PRODUTO'])
```

Eu gostaria de dividir a coluna df_marca_x['PRECO'] / df_marca_y['PRECO'], onde as cidades forem iguais. Por exemplo:

A grosso modo seria

```
if cidade == 'sp':
    df_marca_x['PRECO'] / df_marca_y['PRECO']
```

Isso para todas as cidades, alguém poderia ajudar? Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função where do numpy:

```
np.where(df_marca_x['CIDADE'] == df_marca_y['CIDADE'], df_marca_x['PRECO']/df_marca_y['PRECO'], 0)
```

Quando a condição for atendida ele vai dividir, caso contrário vai retornar zero mas você pode colocar um outro valor caso queira